# Dataframe - reshape dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

| id | item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | apple | orange | water | 2.00 | 1.50 | 0.80 | nothing |
| user2 | banana | milk | apple | 0.50 | 3.50 | 2.00 | 1 bag |

and I want to make it into something like:

| id | item | price | note | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | apple | 2.00 | nothing | 1 |
| user1 | orange | 1.50 | nothing | 2 |
| user1 | water | 0.80 | nothing | 3 |
| user2 | banana | 0.50 | 1 bag | 1 |
| user2 | milk | 3.50 | 1 bag | 2 |
| user2 | apple | 2.00 | 1 bag | 3 |

Is it possible to do it without having to manually input those "item_*"s and "price_*" (since there will be quite a few of them)?

Comment: Look at pd.wide_to_long and with stubs of ['item_', 'price_'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with specified parameters:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['item','price'], 
                     i=['id','note'], 
                     j='number', sep='_').reset_index()
print (df)
      id     note  number    item  price
0  user1  nothing       1   apple    2.0
1  user1  nothing       2  orange    1.5
2  user1  nothing       3   water    0.8
3  user2    1 bag       1  banana    0.5
4  user2    1 bag       2    milk    3.5
5  user2    1 bag       3   apple    2.0
```

Or convert all not `_` columns first, split all columns with `_` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','note'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis((None, 'number'), axis=1).stack().reset_index()
print (df1)
      id     note number    item  price
0  user1  nothing      1   apple    2.0
1  user1  nothing      2  orange    1.5
2  user1  nothing      3   water    0.8
3  user2    1 bag      1  banana    0.5
4  user2    1 bag      2    milk    3.5
5  user2    1 bag      3   apple    2.0
```

Comment: thanks so much @jezrael! the second method works perfectly! but for some reason, wide_to_long gives me an empty df...